# How to the steps inside a resolution work?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I understand from [Watson](http://watson.latech.edu/book/intelligence/intelligenceApproaches2b2.html) that "Resolution is a proof technique that works on conjunctive normal form expressions by (1) selecting two clauses that contain conflicting terms, (2) combining the terms contained in those two clauses, and then (3) canceling the terms that conflict"

So for example
$(\lnot A \lor B) \land ( \lnot B \lor C)$ resolves to $( \lnot A \lor C)$

But I want to see the break down of steps that shows why I can cancel out B with $ \lnot B$

Comment: If B is true then C must be true in order to let the second part be true; if B is false then A must be false to let the first part be true; since B is either true or false, you get the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $B$ is true, then by disjunctive syllogism, $C$ must be true, so $\lnot A \lor C$ is true by [addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_introduction). And if $B$ is false, by disjunctive syllogism, $\lnot A$ must be true, so $\lnot A \lor C$ is true, again by addition.

This means that, whether $A$ is true or not, $\lnot A \lor C$ is true.

---

In another way, we can convert $\lnot A \lor B$ into $A \Rightarrow B$. This means that the statement is just $(A \Rightarrow B) \land (B \Rightarrow C)$. Here, we can accomplish [chaining of implications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_syllogism) to get $A \Rightarrow C$, and rewriting back, we have $\lnot A \lor C$.

Comment: Thank you I like the chain of implications way.